# How to download files synced by OneDrive automatically?

Tags: windows-10, onedrive

When OneDrive syncs folders those folders are in the OneDrive folder. Now what when I'm a developer and don't want this? My CMake doesn't find anything now in my documents folder after I enabled OneDrive syncing because it's moved.

I'm fine with backing up my stuff, but please, Mr. OneDrive, just do the *backup* and don't move all my files around locally.

How do I download all my files now, or rather restore them where they were before syncing, *automatically*? I just want my local folders and files unchanged and have them *mirrored* in the cloud.

---

For example

`C:\Users\me\documents`

was moved like so

`C:\Users\me\OneDrive\documents`

I don't want that. I want the folders to stay where they are. OneDrive shall only mirror folders but not move them arround in my opinion, otherwise the tool is useless for developers.

Comment: One drive moves folder to the cloud only when one move the files manually from another folder to that particular one drive folder. Isn't that so in your case? or Is it backing up everything from every folder in your PC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've "solved" it by manually moving the folders to where they were. It seems that there is no setting or automated way to do this. It's even mentioned in the official tutorials, very unfortunate.